# Change default shipping address in backend

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, customer-address

By default I set default billing and shipping address as shown below,

[image]

In checkout page, i entered different shipping address as shoen below,[image]

This address saved in backend as shown but the default shipping address not changed to the new address. How to fix this.

[image]

Comment: do u want to change from backend?

Comment: Customers can set this as default from My Account area. however admin can simply click the radio button and save the customer. by default Magento doesn't select the newly entered address as default unless its done manually.

Comment: @MTM. Please post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Marius, posted.

Answer (score 2):

Customers can set this as default from My Account area. however admin can simply click the radio button and save the customer. by default Magento doesn't select the newly entered address as default unless its done manually.